# Moveable Splitter bar in Shiny (split.js, react.js splitter, etc.)

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shinyjs, split.js

I was wondering if anyone has ever successfully implemented a moveable splitter bar/pane in their Shiny App before? I am curious on whether these JS libraries have ever been implemented in Shiny:

- Split.js - https://split.js.org/
- React.js splitter layout - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-splitter-layout

Looking forward to hearing your experiences and advice!

Comment: I am also interested to know if anyone has been able to do this.